# All files are not showing up in react-native chrome debugger panel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

I also tried using Ctrl + P to search for the file but it didn't show up. folder such as node_modules and other js files are missing. I tried reloading the app also but I failed

[image]